# How to get External Dir for other app?

Tags: java, android

I have `PackageInfo` of some app in my phone. `PackageInfo.ApplicationInfo.dataDir` gives me internal data path but I want to know how can I get path to `External Data Storage` for that package.
Is there an easy way to just obtain it or do I need to combine path myself from global external storage `dir` and `package name`?

Edit:

`String dirExternalGlobal = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`
`String dirExternalForThisApp = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();`
`String dirInternalForThisApp = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();`
`String dirInternalForOtherApp = otherAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.dataDir;`

`dirExternalGlobal` - gives me `storage/emulated/0`
`dirExternalForThisApp` - gives me `storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_package/files`
`dirInternalForThisApp` - gives me `data/user/0/my_package/files`
`dirInternalForOtherApp` - gives me `data/user/0/other_package`

Now, question is how do i get something like `dirExternalForOtherApp`.
Code that will give me something like: `storage/emulated/0/Android/data/other_package/files`.

`Other package` is an application that is installed on my phone but is not writen by me.

Is there an easy way to get that, or i need to combine `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` with package name?

Comment: What do you mean under `External Data Storage`? Kind of sdcard?

Comment: If you want to access external data storage then try below code,
` String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

It will return a path, along with above code you have to add which file you want to get it from external storage .


`String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +your_file_name`
`File themefolder = new File(path);`

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gives path to global storage, and what i need is path to external storage for package.

Comment: Something like "/sdcard/Android/data/package_name/files/"

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory() gives path to global storage`. No. Look at the function name which clearly states external. Moreover i never heared of global storage. It is unclear what you want or need.

Comment: Did you try `getExternalFilesDir()`?

Comment: `getExternalFilesDir()` gives me external for my app, but i need external for some other app installed on my phone.

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect comments. I hope I'm more clear now.